# Change ReportViewer Currency Format?

Tags: reportviewer, currency

I was wondering how can I change currency format from US ($) to EURO (€) for a specific TextBox in Microsoft ReportViewer?

Because it always displays a dollar sign in front and the format is ##,###.## and as for euro it must be like ##.###,##

Answer (score 5):

To add to the options already stated:

You can set the Language property of the report through Business Intelligence Studio (VS with SSRS project support) to **=User!Language**. This then picks up the culture/locale of the current thread.

I had to use this when users from multiple regions used the same reports.

Answer (score 4):

Well the solution to that problem is to change the general report rdlc language to some of European country (for example I've put it to German language) and the currency field is displaying as it is supposed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the above. I solved my problem with your help however I just wanted to add some detail to this, for those of us who are just starting with report viewer.

The I did this step by step in VB2010

Right Click on the report in Solution explorer
Select Open With
Then select automatic editor selector (xml)
In side the report tags, enter the following tag. the en-gb should be changed to your country code.

```
<Language>en-gb</Language>
```

so it should looks something like this

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
  <Language>en-gb</Language>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSet">
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

As You've discovered, you need to change the Language of the report.

Some extra info: You can't seem to do this via the GUI, you need to edit the <Languauge> element in the xml of the RDLC file. [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153956.aspx) is about RDL files, but the details are the same for RDLC.